# Read Parquet and ORC HDFS file using Pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have my hive External Tables created with InputFormat "Org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.MapredParquetInputFormat" and outputformat: "Org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.MapredParquetOutputFormat".

How do I read these hive table files from hdfs using Pyspark?

Answer (score 0):

If you want SparkSQL to use the hive metastore and access hive tables, then you have to add hive-site.xml in spark conf folder. For [more details](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-hive-tables.html)

```
from os.path import abspath

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import Row

# warehouse_location points to the default location for managed databases and tables
warehouse_location = abspath('spark-warehouse')

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL Hive integration example") \
    .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouse_location) \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM <YOUR TABLE NAME>").show()
```